# How to get the data inside a JSON object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the data inside a JSON object, but when I tried to alert it, or log it, I got **[Object Object]** or **undefined**. Say I'm getting the json object in a div with id = "page". This's what I did:

```
console.log($("#page").val()); //gives undefined
console.log($("#page").toString()); // gives [Object Object]
```

I'm getting the JSON object inside a div I introduced

```
<div id="page"></div>
```

From here I was trying to get the JSON object.

So how do I get the data inside this object?

Comment: `$("#page")[0]`? `$("#page")` is jQuery object, so `toString()` on it gives `[Object object]`

Comment: Please provide code of your page

Comment: You can see the data inside this object with : `JSON.stringify($("#page"))`

Comment: "JSON" does not mean what you think it means ...

Comment: @ R3tep: JSON.stringify isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

To log the object of an DOM element simply:

```
console.log($("#page"));
```

To get the HTML content of it:

```
console.log($("#page").html());
```

Comment: That gave undefined too.